# DNS not responding after enabling AD on Server 2012

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, sharepoint

Beginner question here - I set up a Server 2012 VM in Hyper-V, and had internet access working with a virtual switch.  I'm following this tutorial:

http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/10/create-a-scripted-sharepoint-2013-development-environment-tutorial-part-1.html

And I've gotten to the point where the tutorial says

> (You can now add your internet connection for the rest of the tutorial
>   )!

My internet connection no longer works and if I ping external addresses, I get no response.  If I troubleshoot network issues I see that "The DNS server is not responding".  I have a static IP address set up and the DNS in ipV4 is set to `127.0.0.1`.  How can I re-enable connectivity to my external connection from the vm?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you can't ping an IP address then there's probably an issue affecting all network connectivity, not just DNS.

It looks like the tutorial had you set the system to a static IP - does the IP that it's running on now fit within the configuration of your network?  If not, change the network configuration to one that's appropriate for your network (or switch it back to DHCP, which should work just fine for a single node lab, you'll just get some warnings during the dcpromo).